# Android: NullPointerException in onCreate

Tags: android

I received this crash report in Google Play Developer Console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ZhuangDictActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at ZhuangDictActivity.showChooseDictDialog(ZhuangDictActivity.java:560)
at ZhuangDictActivity.onCreate(ZhuangDictActivity.java:339)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
... 11 more
```

This is under onCreate:

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            dictName = sharedPreferences.getString(PREFERENCES_DICT_NAME, null);
if (dictName == null) {
                showChooseDictDialog(false);
            } else {
                modifyDictVar(dictName);
                setTitle(loadDictInfo());

                initDbFile();
                databaseHelper.initDb();
            }
```

The showChooseDictDialog:

```
private void showChooseDictDialog(boolean cancelable) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dictChooseBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                return filename.contains(".ifo");
            }
        };
        dictFilenames = dictPathFile.list(filter);
        if (dictFilenames.length > 0) {
            dictChooseBuilder.setItems(dictFilenames, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dictName = dictFilenames[which].substring(0, dictFilenames[which].indexOf(".ifo"));

                    modifyDictVar(dictName);
                    initDbFile();
                    databaseHelper.initDb();

                    if (new File(ifoFileName).isFile()) {
                        setTitle(loadDictInfo());
                    }

                    if (new File(idxFileName).isFile() && dictFile.isFile()) {
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(ZhuangDictActivity.PREFERENCES_DICT_NAME, dictName).commit();

                        // dbHelper.dropTable(tableName);
                        if (!databaseHelper.isTableExist(tableName)) {
                            databaseHelper.beginTransaction();
                            databaseHelper.createTable(tableName);
                            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
                                String temp = DatabaseHelper.transTableName(c);
                                databaseHelper.createTable(temp);
                            }
                            databaseHelper.setTransactionSuccessful();
                            databaseHelper.endTransaction();
                            new LoadDictIndexAsyncTask().execute(dictName);
                        }
                    } else {
                        showDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.choose_dict_content));
                    }
                }   
            });
            dictChooseBuilder.setCancelable(cancelable).setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.choose_dict_title))
                    .create().show();
        } else {
            dictChooseBuilder.setCancelable(cancelable).setMessage(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.choose_dict_content)).create().show();
        }
    }
```

The complete source code of ZhuangDictAcitivity.java is available here: https://code.google.com/p/zhuang-dict/source/browse/trunk/ZhuangDict/src/cn/wangdazhuang/zdict/ZhuangDictActivity.java

Anyone know the solution for this?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the place where error occures?

Comment: What's on row 560 of the ZhuanDictActivity.java version that was built with that app version?

Comment: Try to provide the context in your alertdialog as ` AlertDialog.Builder dictChooseBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ZhuangDictActivity.this);`

Comment: Line 560 is the if (dictFilenames.length > 0) { under showChooseDictDialog.

Comment: @user2872856 check if dictFilenames is not null

Comment: `File.list()` may return `null` e.g. if the file is not a directory. The code does not check for `!= null` before accessing the `length` field.

Comment: The report says there is null value (line 560 of ZhuangDictActivity). And since u refer to .length of dictFilenames, makes me think that it is your null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments the problem is here:

```
dictFilenames = dictPathFile.list(filter);
if (dictFilenames.length > 0) {
```

[`File.list()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) may return `null` for example if the `File` is not a directory. And accessing the `length` field of a `null` array leads to `NullPointerException`. The following change probably helps:

```
dictFilenames = dictPathFile.list(filter);
if (dictFileNames != null && dictFilenames.length > 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is I only know about this error from the Developer Console. I do not face this error when tested on emulator and my device. So how should I know whether this problem has been solved? Sorry, I'm still new in Android app development.

Comment: @user2872856 Since you don't have the exact steps/environment to reproduce the crash, you cannot know for sure the problem is really fixed. But knowing the crash exception with exact line number like in this case, you can reason backwards the immediate cause for the crash (null array reference) and a workaround for it (check for null before using). The code makes many assumptions about the runtime environment that may not be true for all devices and users, e.g. 1) external storage exists 2) it is writable 3) it contains a folder of the given name.